# For loop that shifts array's last value to the left to replace a value x in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, for-loop

I have the following method that accepts a generic object (When I use it, I pass an `Integer` object) and removes the object at that position in the array. Note that my

```
private currentSize;
private E[] list;
...
public E remove(E obj){

    for (int i = 1; i < currentSize; i++)
        if( ((Comparable<E>)obj).compareTo(list[i]) == 0){

            for(int j = i; j < currentSize; j++)
                list[j] = list[j+1];
            currentSize--;
            return obj;
        }

    return null;
}
```

I have two other methods that relate to my method above.

```
for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++)
    list.addLast(i);
```

The code above adds 10 sequential `int`s to my array. (This works perfectly. Note that the `addLast` method parses only a primitive `int`, because I have it declared like so in `addLast()` )

```
for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++){
   list.remove(new Integer(i));  
}
```

The code above removes those 10 `int`s we added before. My `remove()` method kind of works, it removes all `Integer` objects from the array except 1.

My output when I call both `addLast` and then `remove` methods in another class:

> "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Now removing them all

> Current size of list: (should be zero) 1"

That one in front of (should be zero) is not supposed to be there. Please note that I am trying to ignore the `0` index of the array. Also, I would like to know the way of implementing a backwards implementation of my inner-most for loop `for(int j = i; j < currentSize; j++)`. Sort of like `[1,2,3,4,5] ...` if I want to "remove" #2 in the array, I would start from the end of the array instead of the beginning.

addLast method code:

```
public void addLast(E obj){
        list[currentSize++] = obj;
        //System.out.println(currentSize);
        }
```

Print all the objects in array:

```
for(int x : list)
    System.out.print(x + " ");
System.out.println("\n");
```

Comment: Show *all* code that you are calling. Eg remove only looks at indices 1 through currentSize-1 which is bad if currentsize is the number of elements but ok if currentSize is the number of elements plus one. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also your writing is unclear, particularly when you are referring to parts of things.

Comment: Re "I would start from the end of the array": Do you mean you want an operator remove_nth_last(n)?

Comment: Re "list[currentSize++] = obj": This should be if (currentSize+1 <= list.length-1) list[++currentSize] = obj but requires that list be initialized and currentSize be 0 for an empty list. Re "for(int x : list)": This requires that list[0] has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java are zero bases. So you have to start at zero in your loops:

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
   list.remove(new Integer(i));  
}
```

And:

```
private currentSize;
private E[] list;
...
public E remove(E obj){

    for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
        if( ((Comparable<E>)obj).compareTo(list[i]) == 0){

            for(int j = i; j < currentSize; j++)
                list[j] = list[j+1];
            currentSize--;
            return obj;
        }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I want to ignore the 0th index of the array, as if it didnt exist. If you can see, in my addMethod I start at i = 1 as well. The real number of elements in the list is held by the currentSize variable

Answer (score 0):

Your loop in the `remove` method ignores the first element of the array (1 in your case), so it will never be removed :

```
for (int i = 1; i < currentSize; i++)
```

change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
```

Let's look at your addLast method :

```
list[currentSize++] = obj;
```

When the list is empty (i.e. currentSize is 0), `currentSize++` returns 0 (since it's the postfix increment) and the first element is added to `list[0]`. Therefore when removing an element from the array you must consider all the indices from 0 to currentSize-1.

Comment: The thing is that I want to ignore the index 0 of the array... so the actual starting index would be 1.

Comment: @JackGal Does your `addLast` method ignore the first index of the array? You didn't show the code of that method.

Comment: If you can see, in my addMethod I start at i = 1 as well. The real number of elements in the list is held by the currentSize variable. Please refer to my edit to see the addLast method. Thanks!

Comment: @JackGal The fact that the first number you add with `addLast` is `1` doesn't mean that `1` is added in the `1` index of the array. Actaully, `list[currentSize++] = ob` means the first element would be added to the `0` index of the array.

Comment: I just noticed that... I changed it to `list[++currentSize] = obj` but it throws a an error: `ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException`. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @JackGal In which method do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71332/discussion-between-jack-gal-and-eran).

Comment: I updated my code so you can see that I use an Iterator & for loop to go through all the objects in my array

Answer (score 0):

> That one in front of (should be zero) is not supposed to be there.

Looks like your loop should be `i <= currentSize`. Ie you are probably not checking whether the item to remove is the last one. So when you ask to remove 1 it isn't found.

But you are not giving enough information.

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> I would like to know the way of implementing a backwards
>   implementation of my inner-most for loop `for(int j = i; j < currentSize; j++)`.

Why? And what does this even mean? If you want to keep the elements in order then your current code puts each one directly into its correct place already. If you don't care about order then you could just move the last element to where the to-be-removed element is by `list[i] = list[currentSize--]` instead of looping on j.

But again you have not given us enough information about what the external behaviour of your operators is supposed to be or about how external state is represented by internal state.